# Codeigniter Query returns Empty results for Special Character

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have a simple query which works just fine in workbench or phpmyadmin .

```
Ex1 select * from tabel1 where name='(Jhon Rick)';
Ex2: seelct* from tabel1 where name='John';
```

Ex1 works in Normal Console or phpmyadmin,but doesn't on CI.

Ex2 works both on Console as well as CI, so i assume the issue is with **parenthesis ()**

When i prepare the same query using CI, empty results are returned for **EX1**.
On debugging the query i get the same query as above.

Possible issue with CI db driver?
Any help regarding this.

Comment: have you loaded your database?

Comment: Maybe you should use `like` ?
`select * from tabel1 where name like '%John%'`

Comment: What if you use the query builder syntax? `$query = $this->db->get_where('tabel1', array('name' => '(Jhon Rick)'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.
PHP buy default encodes Unicode character Parenthesis () as HTML entity

```
i.e     &#40; and   &#41; respectively for ()
```

In order to fix it, i had to just decode it back using

**html_entity_decode($varName);**